# Python 2.7: set the value of a variable with a symbolic expression written in a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file where I wrote a list of symbolic equations. I need to set the value of a variable with this list.

In other words I'm looking for a command that automatically "copy" all I have written in the text file and "paste" it into an expression such this:

```
a = all_it's_written_in_the_text_file
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean you want to read a file into a string? Or did you want to *execute* (evaluate) the expressions from the file as if they were Python code?

Comment: Explain more your question or it will keep down voting, though I'm still not of the down voters...:P

Comment: The second: I have a text file where I wrote a list with symbolic elements (let's say: [x[0], x[1], 2*x[2]]) and I need to introduce a symbolic variable (for example: myfun = [x[0], x[1], 2*x[2]]) that has to be a list, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(filename, "rt") as f:
    a = eval(f.read())
```

Comment: I strongly suspect this is about evaluation, not just reading.

Comment: Running this code "a" will be a string, I need "a" to be a list. Thank you.

Comment: To be a list of what?

Comment: It has to be a list of symbolic expression. The text file is already written with the correct syntax to be read by Python. I only need a way to "copy" the list I have in the file and "paste" it on the right side of the equal (i.e. myfun = [list_written_in_the_file]).

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, my code missed "eval()". Sorry I can't vote you up because I haven't enough reputation.